# Replace all strings and wrap as html

Tags: reactjs, grunt-string-replace

I want to find and replace strings in html and replace them as tags.
from `my name is ron and his name is ben`
to   `my name is <b>ron</b> and his name is <b>ben</b>`

Here is my code, works partially:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gjriyz

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = ["ron", "ben"];
  const str = "my name is ron and his name is ben";
  let res = "";
  for (var i in arr) {
    res = str.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: res }} /> <br />
      <br /> 
      expected result: <br />
      my name is <b>ron</b> and his name is <b>ben</b>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you didn't save your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wood-tzith). All I see is the default react template.

Comment: @DrewReese fixed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gjriyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only ever updating `res` from the original string versus incrementally updating `res`, so the last replace operation trumps all.

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = ["ron", "ben"];
  const str = "my name is ron and his name is ben";
  let res = str;
  for (var i in arr) {
    // iterate on res, not str
    // res = str.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>");
    res = res.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: res }} /> <br />
      <br /> 
      expected result: <br />
      my name is <b>ron</b> and his name is <b>ben</b>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is correct, you are replacing str in the first loop, and then replacing the original value again in the second. This ignores the changes made in the first

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, you are not concatenating the results here.

```
 let res = "";
  for (var i in arr) {
    res = str.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>");
  }
```

This must be like below.

```
 let res = str;
  for (var i in arr) {
    res = res.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>");
  }
```

Comment: Not working, please use my link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gjriyz